# I have problems instaling vcredist_x86 on win7

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7

When i try to instal it it gives me this error,it says that vcredist_x86 isnt installed properly,and when i try to install it manually i cant,it gives me the same error.

```
Problem Event Name: BEX

Application Name:   install.exe_Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008

Application Version:    9.0.30729.4148

 Application Timestamp: 4a597677

 Fault Module Name: install.exe

Fault Module Version:   9.0.30729.4148

 Fault Module Timestamp:    4a597677

  Exception Offset: 0003f04b

  Exception Code:   c0000417

  Exception Data:   00000000

  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48

  Locale ID:    9242

  Additional Information 1: 7e02

  Additional Information 2: 7e02000cc9a98b1fce2b3132e623d86d

  Additional Information 3: 7a95

  Additional Information 4: 7a95b5323f1cf363784ef70b5804c9c1
```

This happens when i try to instal [NFS hot pursuit](http://hotpursuit.needforspeed.com/). What should i do?

Comment: Did you download it from piratebay? ;

Comment: yeah...sadly...

Comment: try another torrent

Comment: its not about the torrent,its bout that i cant install vcredist_x86,whatever i do. thats the problem

Comment: I'm going to ignore the discussion about torrents. Did you download the vcredist package from [this website](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en)? It's a free set of runtime components that programs written in Visual C++ require. Usually the application will include it as part of the installer, but in this case, it might not have or it might be corrupted. Download them yourself and install them before attempting to install your program.

Comment: yeah,ive downloaded it from the microsofts site,but still its not working,gives me the same error (external installer stopped working)

EDIT
the game works on my laptop but on desktop does not,i mean i can install it on lap top,but not here because of the vcredist

Comment: solved (only had to update windows)